# Grab text from webpage using vb

Tags: vb.net

i want code that grab text from webpage

here is the html

```
<div><span>Version : </span> " 1.3"</div>
```

so i want **1.3**  text in textbox1

Answer (score 1):

To manipulate HTML elements/documents easily, you need to install HTML Agility Pack. You can get it from NuGet at: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack

After you have it, you can do a lot of magic with HTML documents/tags.

```
Dim voHAP As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
voHAP.LoadHtml("<div><span>Version : </span> "" 1.3""</div>")
Dim voDiv As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode = voHAP.DocumentNode.Elements("div")(0)

voDiv.RemoveChild(voDiv.Element("span"))
Dim vsText As String = Replace(voDiv.InnerText, """", "").Trim
```

The `vsText` variable will contain your value of 1.3. The final `Replace()` function is to remove the unwanted " characters in the string.

Comment: Thanks for this but there can be another case too .. so if in place 1.3 ,it will be 1.4 or 2.2  ,then what should i do. And one more thing i will not know about what is going to be there . I only know is that there is going to be <div><span>Version : </span>  sometext(which i don't know) </div>  ... so can u please give me code for this.

Comment: Have you try it. The code above works for any value.

Comment: nope bcuz i am not getting that how it will read or find text from webpage as no webpage path is there .Or it will automatically get it from live webpage.

Comment: Wow... u totally have zero knowledge eh? Load the webpage and put in the html into voHAP.LoadHtml() line.

Comment: i have just started vb.net about 1-2 weeks before ..that's why i don't know